# Nothing will get my register_activation_hook to work

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, hook, activation

Okay I have been looking everywhere for the solution to this. For some ungodly reason, I have not been able to find the right fix and I really do not understand what is going wrong.

I am attempting to use register_activation_hook and register_deactivation_hook. Here is my code.

```
register_activation_hook(__FILE__, 'plugin_on' );
register_deactivation_hook(__FILE__, 'plugin_off' );

function plugin_on() {

    $file = 'people.txt';
    // Open the file to get existing content
    $current = file_get_contents($file);
    // Append a new person to the file
    $current .= "1\n";
    // Write the contents back to the file
    file_put_contents($file, $current);

    wp_schedule_event( time(), 'minutely', 'my_daily_event' );
}

add_action( 'my_daily_event',  'mail_test' );

function plugin_off() {
    wp_clear_scheduled_hook('my_daily_event');
}
```

plugin_on is never called.

Here are some things I already tried or things I know are not the issue.

1. My plugin folder is not symlinked.
2. This file is definitely called when opening the homepage of the site.
3. the `__FILE__` path is correct. It points to this file, and this is the main plugin file.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I tested this on a test plugin and passed the test in every condition I applied by reflecting an option update. What makes you think this isn't working?

Comment: The code to write to the file in the function does not write into the file. If I put the code outside the function, it does write to the file.